# Compile scala code with "import org.apache.spark.SparkContext" without sbt

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have started to build a small scala code.
It will be expanded to open SparkContext and do some data processing.
As of now I have only imported 3 spark libraries to run a simple code.

I am getting error "error: object apache is not a member of package org".

Question is: How can I compile manually using scalac so that the compilation process can include the Spark libraries - without Maven or sbt?

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object HelloWorld {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

Comment: download each package from the internet and locate properly. Without sbt or maver it is really annoying.

Comment: You would need to manually manage the classpath of the compiler. The moment you need more than two libraries and have more than two files, it would be very annoying. Any reason why you do not want to use any build tool? Can you explain your use case? Maybe you may be better with the **spark-shell** or a notebook environment like **Zeppelin**, also you may try **Ammonite** scripts with let you download libraries directly in code.

Comment: Seems a pointless question to me. It's a bit like asking can I boil an egg without water. Why not do it the easier way?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was trying this as I practice Scala/Spark in a shared workspace on a web site for a fee. I am not entitled to save or install there. So I was trying to compile scala code with some option mentioning the location of all the necessary files. I am now trying through the training web site.